# Is There a Word Which Means "Not a Ten-Foot Display"?

Tags: terminology

I'm designing a web-based arrivals board which has:

1. A ["ten foot"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10-foot_user_interface) version for display on a big TV (viewed at a distance)
2. A "regular" version for laptop/phone

What do folk say for #2?

- Regular
- Classical
- Desktop
- Close-Up
- Non-Ten-Foot

Comment: What do people who need to understand this think? I would rather speak in terms of large displays/normal displays but I'm not one of them. This is hard to answer without knowing the context in which it is used and by who. But once you are able to add that information you'll probably know the answer yourself .

Comment: I've gone with "desktop" in case any one cares 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Personal device

> Typically refers to a laptop, tablet or smartphone owned by an individual.

<sub>*Source [thefreedictionary.com](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/personal+device)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I would use "arm's length display" or "arm's reach display".  It's clear that it's close to the user, and it conveys a contrasting distance to "ten-foot display".